# rubyのチェーンメソッド関数の作り方

Tags: ruby

rubyでチェーンメソッドが使える関数の作り方を教えて下さい。

```
"string".hoge()
```

hogeをつくりたい

```
def hoge(){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

クラスにメソッドを付け加えたいときは、[モンキーパッチ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%83%81) をします。

```
class String
  def hoge
    # メソッドの中身
  end
end

"string".hoge
```

チェーンメソッドにするのは簡単です。メソッドが `self` か 同じクラスのオブジェクトを返すようにします。

```
class Foo
  def m1
    puts "hi"
    self
  end

  def m2
    puts "bye"
    self
  end
end

f = Foo.new.m2.m2
f.m1.m2.m2.m1

# 出力
# bye
# bye
# hi
# bye
# bye
# hi
```

チェーンメソッドではないですが、初期化の際にコンパクトな書き方を可能にするために、ブロックを渡すようにすることもできます。この場合ブロックを新しいオブジェクト内で実行させるために、[instance_eval](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/BasicObject/i/instance_eval.html)というメソッドを使います。

```
class Foo
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def m1
    puts "hi"
    self
  end

  def m2
    puts "bye"
    self
  end
end

f = Foo.new do
  m1()
  m2()
end

# 出力
# hi
# bye
```

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto 直してくれてありがとうございます。私はまだ習っています。

Answer (score 0):

チェーンメソッドではなくメソッドチェーン(チェイン)です。メソッドのチェインです。

メソッドチェインは、「前のメソッドの戻り値をレシーバとしたメソッド呼び出しができる構文」に過ぎません。

```
str = " abc ".strip # => " abc "
str.upcase # => "ABC"
#これをつなげてこうかける
" abc ".stip.upcase #=> "ABC"
#冗長な括弧を付けるとこう
(" abc ".stip).upcase #=> "ABC"
```

呼び出す側の話ですので、メソッド定義(呼び出される側)でなにか特別なことをする必要はありません。メソッドチェインで別のメソッドが呼ばれることを前提にしているなら、そのメソッドを受け取れるクラスのオブジェクトを戻り値として返すだけです。

「selfか同じクラスのオブジェクトを返さないといけない」という回答がついていますが誤りです。上記の通り単なるメソッド呼び出しの構文にすぎないので、どのようなクラスのオブジェクトを返しても、そのオブジェクトが受け取れるメソッドなら続けて書けます

```
12345.to_s.length #=> 5
```